# Determining integers $a,b$ given their $\gcd$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Find integers a and b such that $6=67a+25b$.

The first thing I tried was recognizing this equation as a Diophantine Equation, but is there another way to determine integers a and b without utilizing the method of Diophantine Equations? I also tried to rewrite the given equation as: $6=(a+b)+6(11a+4b)$ and took cases, but didn't obtain integer values for a and b. This problem is from a chapter that deals with Working Backwards.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: You could observe that $1 = 67 \cdot 3 - 25 \cdot 8$, and so multiplying both sides by $6$ gives you that $a = 18, b = -48$ is a solution.